# Scrolling list of labels on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, label, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a scrollbar for my labels. For the moment, if the users create too many labels, the sizes of the button and of the text zone are reduced, that's why I wanted to create a scrollbar then if there is too many labels, they will not change the aspect of the window.

This is my actual code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include "LibQt.hpp"

LibQt::LibQt() : QWidget()
{
  this->size_x = 500;
  this->size_y = 500;
  QWidget::setWindowTitle("The Plazza");
  setFixedSize(this->size_x, this->size_y);
  manageOrder();
}

LibQt::~LibQt()
{
}

void LibQt::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
  if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
    QCoreApplication::quit();
  else
    QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
}

void LibQt::manageOrder()
{
  this->converLayout = new QFormLayout;
  this->testline = new QLineEdit;
  this->m_button = new QPushButton("Send");
  this->m_button->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
  this->m_button->setFont(QFont("Comic Sans MS", 14));
  this->converLayout->addRow("Order : ", this->testline);
  this->converLayout->addWidget(this->m_button);
  QObject::connect(m_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ClearAndGetTxt()));
  CreateLabel("test");
  CreateLabel("test2");
}

void            LibQt::CreateLabel(std::string text)
{
  QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(text);

  this->label = new QLabel(qstr);
  this->converLayout->addWidget(this->label);
  this->setLayout(converLayout);
}

std::string     LibQt::ClearAndGetTxt()
{
  QString txt = this->testline->text();

  if (!txt.isEmpty())
    {
      this->usertxt = txt.toStdString();
      std::cout << this->usertxt << std::endl;
      this->testline->clear();
      CreateLabel(this->usertxt);
      return (this->usertxt);
    }
  return (this->usertxt);
}

std::string     LibQt::getUsertxt()
{
  return (this->usertxt);
}
```

And this is the .hpp :

```
#ifndef _LIBQT_HPP_
#define _LIBQT_HPP_

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class   LibQt : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  LibQt();
  ~LibQt();
  void manageOrder();
  std::string getUsertxt();
  void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
  void keyPressEventEnter(QKeyEvent *event);
  void CreateLabel(std::string text);
public slots:
  std::string ClearAndGetTxt();
protected:
  int   size_x;
  int   size_y;
  QPushButton *m_button;
  QLineEdit *testline;
  std::string usertxt;
  QLabel *label;
  QFormLayout *converLayout;
};

#endif /* _LIBQT_HPP_ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different solutions depending on what precisely do you want

1. [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) is Qt widget class for scrollable text. By turning off text interaction flags, frame style and unsetting background color you will basically get scrollable `QLabel`
2. [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html) as a more generic solution

Comment: Is it exact that If I do a qscrollarea, it takes all my widgets, and the qscrollarea has to be itself in my layout ?

Comment: @Michael003, you have to: 1. place scroll area inside your widget 2. create scrollable widget 3. [set](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#setWidget) scrollable widget 4. put child widgets inside scrollable widget